# command substitution not working in alias?

Tags: shell, alias, pipeline, command-substitution

I wanted to make an alias for launching a vim session with all the c/header/makefiles, etc loaded into the buffer.

```
shopt -s extglob
alias vimc="files=$(ls -A *.?(c|h|mk|[1-9]) .gitconfig [mM]akefile 2>/dev/null); [[ -z $files ]] || vim $files"
```

When I run the command enclosed within the quotations from the shell, it works but when run as the alias itself, it **does not**. Running `vimc`, causes vim to launch only in the first matched file(which happens to be the Makefile) and the other files(names) **are executed as commands** for some reason(of course unsuccessfully). I tried fiddling around and it seems that the command substitution introduces the problem. Because running only the `ls` produces expected output.

I [cannot use `xargs` with vim](https://superuser.com/questions/336016/invoking-vi-through-find-xargs-breaks-my-terminal-why) because it breaks the terminal display.

Can anyone explain what might be causing this ?
Here is some output:

```
$ ls
Makefile  readme  main.1  main.c  header.h  config.mk

$ vimc
main.1: command not found
main.c: command not found
.gitignore: command not found
header.h: command not found
config.mk: command not found
```

**On an related note**, would it be possible to do what I intend to do above in a "single line", i.e without storing it into a variable `files` and checking to see if it is empty, using only the output stream from `ls`?

Comment: Please read bout difference between single quotes and double quotes. So why not a function?

Comment: I tried single quotes instead and it worked. I'm reading up on it right now, thanks for the advice, I never really thought too much about the quotations I used in aliases. Any thoughts about the second part ?

Comment: @FirstUser : In your definition, the command substitution is executed at the time the alias is defined, not executed. Aside from this, why do you need `ls` to generate a list of files?

Comment: I dont want to open vim unless there are files in the directory matching the pattern.